# Printer friendly Page Using Response.Write

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.write

I am required to create a print friendly Page containing just a few data fields from my one-page website. I have been told to do this by using `Response.Write`.

I was given this clue in my task:

> The trick is to use the `Response` method, which is provided by the Page
>   Class (more precisely, it is provided by a parent class named
>   `System.Web`).  What you show on the screen is managed by the `System.Web`
>   object and using the `Response` method you can put anything you want in
>   there.

I've done some Googling but this doesn't seem like the way this should be done, however for some reason it must be done this way.

Basically it must create a print-friendly page by clearing the page and passing through only some variables to display plain black on white.

Comment: I think one of the most printer friendly ways would be to use some sort of PDF library like iTextSharp to generate a PDF of what you need. No changing the requirements?

Comment: Have you abandoned this question?

Answer (score 1):

> I have been told to do this by using `Response.Write`.

Whoever told you to do it this way is wrong, wrong, wrong.

If you need to make any kind of web page "printer friendly", then the right way to do it is via [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

So if your page currently has CSS like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Then you simply create a second style sheet that does everything you need to make your page "printer friendly, and then change your html to include the `print` version.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
```

Then in your `print.css` stylesheet, you can use styles that are directly related to a print view. Some examples can be found in [this link](http://www.cssnewbie.com/default-print-stylesheet-template/#.UbdJwvb71FE)

```css
/*Make your layout similar to a sheet of paper*/
body, #content, #container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    background: #fff url(none);
}

/*Hide navigation, ads, and anything else you don't want printed*/
#topnav, #navbar, #nav, #sidebar, .ad, .noprint {
    display: none; 
}

/*Set a new default font*/
body {
    font: 1em Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #000; 
}

/*Style your headings*/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
h1 { font-size: 250%; }
h2 { font-size: 175%; }
h3 { font-size: 135%; }
h4 { font-size: 100%; font-variant: small-caps; }
h5 { font-size: 100%; }
h6 { font-size: 90%; font-style: italic; }

/*Display the links associated with hyperlinks*/
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #00c;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline; }

#content a:link:after, #content a:visited:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
}
```